What Is The Name For Analogues of Spherical Harmonics on Projective Spaces
On the sphere $S^d$, an arbitrary function $f \in L^2(S^d)$ can be expanded as $\sum_{k = 0}^\infty f_k$, where $f_k$ is a spherical harmonic of degree $k$. This expansion is a result of the symmetry group $SO(d+1)$ acting on $S^d$, i.e. the spherical harmonics are obtained from the representation of $SO(d+1)$ on $L^2(S^d)$.
The space $\mathbb{RP}^d$ has a similar expansion from the action of $SO(d+1)$. The decomposition of $L^2(\mathbb{RP}^d)$ using this action is really just the spherical harmonic expansion, where we only consider spherical harmonics that are even functions on $S^d$, and thus descend to functions on $\mathbb{RP}^d$.
Representation theory likewise gives rise to expansions of $\mathbb{CP}^d$ and $\mathbb{HP}^d$ in terms of similar functions from the actions of the symmetry groups on these spaces. But what are the names these functions are called in the literature (e.g. something like 'projective harmonics')?
